# What changes are needed if I change directory structure?

Tags: craft3

I can't have a mess of craft stuff at the root of my server so I try to use the following directory structure, with craft files and folders gathered in a craft directory :

```
craft
-- config
-- modules
-- storage
-- vendor
-- etc...
www
-- index.php
-- web.config
-- etc.
```

This structure gives me a 500 error.
I assume I can change a path variable somewhere, but I just can't find where. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the path to Craft in your `www/index.php` file.

```
define('CRAFT_BASE_PATH', __DIR__ . '/../craft/' ); // <- in your case something like this
```

The constant `CRAFT_BASE_PATH` must point to your `/craft` folder

Comment: Your code does NOT work btw, but I replaced _ _ DIR _ _ with the full server path for the craft folder and it does the trick

Answer (score 1):

You should not be placing Craft at the root of your server, ideally you would place it one level above the *Web Root* directory, i.e. the one your domain name resolves to.

So, depending on your server OS you would need something like `var/www/example.com/craft/` and `var/www/example.com/www/` where `var/www/example.com/www/` is the Web Root.

Just to add, this is the structure Craft is configured to expect, out-of-the-box, but with the publicly acceesible folder being `public_html/` rather than `www/`.

Comment: [craft] is above web root, [www] is the web root

Comment: In that case it should work fine. Have you made changes to .htaccess?

Comment: Full server path needed to be included in place or the magic _ _ DIR _ _ constant in index.php

Comment: It _could_ work with craft2, but craft 3 has a different folder structure . Thanks for helping anyway